# How do I scale in, and then extrude a smaller square column up

Tags: modeling, extrude

[image]I am 3 weeks in to Blender and completely stuck.  Watched all the videos that show a face selected.  Then the face is scaled in or out then extruded and repeat.  My problem is that I have been unable to find the answer to online or in the manual deals with the scaling part.  The object edges follow my face when I select the face and scale in or out.  I can not just get the face plane to move independently.  Please help.

[image]

Comment: are you looking to inset (`I` button) a face?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using (g) on your keyboard to grab the face and move it?

you can also extrude in any direction by pressing (e) to extrude, and then the direction you wish to extrude in.

e, x - this will extrude in the direction of X. You can also use (g) after you extrude to fine tune your extrusion

g, x

If this is not what you want, please be a little more descriptive with your question.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Internet Warriors.  Let me see if I can add more.  The below pic is the top view showing an attempt to scale the top face in on a cube.  I wanted to scale in and then extrude a smaller square column up,  The top pic is the front view that shows my problem I am having.  The top face is not releasing from the rest of the cube like everyone's videos.  My process is in edit mode with just the top face selected.  I hit s and with the mouse move inward and the  pics tell the rest.  I hope this information helps describes my problem better. Thanks

Comment: oh, yes I tried g.

Comment: Instead of extruding and then scaling in, just press i to inset, then once you've scaled in to the point you want, press e to extrude in your desired direction. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [**Inset Faces**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/inset.html?highlight=inset#inset-faces) tool.

Using **face select** mode, select the face, press <kbd>I</kbd> and move the mouse and then pull the face in the direction you need.

[image]

Alternatively you can use the Depth settings to have a more precise control of the height.

[image]

Comment: I think op doesn't want the pyramid form. more like a cube on a cube shape. you can achieve that by pressing "e" instead of moving the plane after insetting it with "i"